# How to select a unique combination of 2 columns and insert the results into a 3rd table with auto_increment feature

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table, called pat_authors with 2 columns- last_name, first_initials
I want to select distinct combinations of the two columns. The following command works to retrieve the correct information:

```
select distinct last_name, first_initials from pat_authors;
```

However, I want to retrieve the same information and then insert it into another table, called unique_authors, where unique_authors has 3 columns - authorID,last_name,first_initials.

I've tried so many variations of code, I'm going crazy. Here are what I considered to be my 2 closest to being correct attempts:

```
select distinct author_last_name, author_initials into uniqueauthors from pat_authors;
```

Which gave me an error - `1327:undeclared variable: uniqueauthors`

I've also tried

```
insert into uniqueauthors select distinct author_last_name, author_initials from pat_authors;
```

Which gives me `Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.` Here I thought I'd be fine because my `authorID` column is `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the `INSERT` statement wouldn't know which two columns to insert data into from the two columns in the `SELECT`. You need to either explicitly specify the columns you're going to `INSERT` into:

```
INSERT INTO uniqueauthors (last_name, first_initials)
SELECT DISTINCT author_last_name, author_initials
FROM pat_authors
```

Or you can leave the column specification implicit. However, if you do that, you'll need to make sure there are an equal number of columns (in matching order) in the `SELECT` as there are columns in the table definition (even including the auto-incrementing column). How do can you still have the column auto-increment? You can simply specify `NULL` as the first column in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO uniqueauthors 
SELECT DISTINCT NULL, author_last_name, author_initials 
FROM pat_authors
```

**Useful tip:** whenever you try to insert a `NULL` value into a auto-incrementing column, it will simply insert the auto-incremented value instead.

Comment: I thought I tried this solution already, but I guess I got something wrong. Your suggestion worked perfectly; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use all columns, you need to specify what columns you going to use

```
insert into uniqueauthors(last_name, first_initials) select distinct author_last_name, author_initials from pat_authors;
```

or just set a value to all columns

```
insert into uniqueauthors select null, author_last_name, author_initials from pat_authors GROUP BY author_last_name, author_initials;
```